# Querying with where() and get() methods in Laravel ORM

Tags: php, orm, laravel-5

I use Laravel framework and i want to fetch result from DB and diplay it in View.I have method in controller:

```
public function showImage(){
$project=Projects::where('id','>','0')->get(array('description'));
return view('about')->with('project',$project);
}
```

but result in view is diplayed like this: {"description":"Some description"}; {"description":"Another description"}; ,with column name,curly braces and double quotes.How i can get rid of column name,curly braces and double quotes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Retrieve your data like this:

```
public function showImage(){
$project=Projects::where('id','>','0')->get();
return view('about')->with(compact('project'));
}
```

And then in your view file you can look through the collection like this:

```
@foreach($project as $project)
 {{ $project->description }}
@endforeach
```